# What is the name of this connector

Tags: connector, identification

Does anybody know the name of the cable that should be inserted in this connector? I lost it so I cannot make a picture.

I know it is a power cable where the other side is inserted in a 200-240 V (non grounded) Dutch (European) wall socket/out.

These types come in two sizes, the most generic is slightly bigger, this one is smaller (but for both I don't know the name).

The distance between the pins is about 6 mm, the horizontal distance 11 mm, and the height around 6 mm.

Brand: Philips
Type : Hair (not beard) shaver
Model: (I will add this later, not near the device)
Type : Power connector (other end of cable to ungrounded Dutch/Europen 220 V wall outlet/socket)
Marks: (I will add this later)

[image: Connector]

Update:

The model is Philips, HC3410. I could find an adapter but those are over 30 euro including shipping (more than the entire product). However, I found via AliExpress and a Dutch site a compatibility list so I hope it will work. I will not in 2 to 8 weeks.

For those who are interested:

Compatibility list: [Compability list](https://www.mijnonderdelenhuis.nl/a-40225869/philips/adapter-philips-scheerapparaat-adapter-philips-crp136-01-272217190129-hq8505-422203630181/#description)

Adapter: [Adapter at AliExpress](https://www.aliexpress.com/item/High-quality-1PCS-15V-360mA-380mA-2-Prong-EU-Wall-Plug-AC-Power-Adapter-Charger-for/32623776642.html?spm=2114.search0104.3.9.Equ7HW&ws_ab_test=searchweb0_0,searchweb201602_5_10152_10065_10151_10344_10068_10345_10342_5660015_10343_10340_10341_10541_10084_10083_10304_10307_10301_10177_10060_10155_10154_10056_10055_10539_10537_10312_10313_10536_10059_10314_10534_10533_100031_5650015_10550_10103_10073_10551_10102_10552_5670015_10553_10554_10557_10142_10107-10553,searchweb201603_30,ppcSwitch_2&btsid=f4576409-62bf-4d92-a356-ac97d9402bbf&algo_expid=030325ab-2930-4d4e-a402-e69f6a32130f-1&algo_pvid=030325ab-2930-4d4e-a402-e69f6a32130f)

Comment: In the future, it would help if you described the device, manufacturer, model number, voltage if marked.

Comment: @user71659 you are fully right ... I will do when I am at my gf's house (she has the device).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your device is likely a Philips Norelco shaver. It is a DC low-voltage polarized connector which was used after it was decided that unconnected line-voltage cords and sinks don't mix. I believe it is proprietary, I haven't seen it anywhere else. If you want a replacement, just look for the proper charger for your model of razor.

[image]

Comment: I searched (forgot to put the model in my description) ... and I cannot remember it. It is a Philips shaver (for head hair, not beard). I checked for a replacement but couldn't find (it's quite old).

Comment: The problem is they appear to vary. The one I own has an output of 8 V 100 mA (despite the shaver being marked 8 V 1 W). Ones I found online just looking for "Philips shaver adapter" seem to output 15 V. You'll have to see if the shaver is labeled.

Comment: It seems it might be tricky to find one in that case. Thanks for the info.

Comment: Thinking about it, I bet the lower voltage is for NiMH shavers and the higher voltage for Li-Ion.

Comment: I guess your answer was closest and the connector type does not really have a name since it is proprietary. Btw, I ordered a (hopefully compatible) adapter.